# Unity C# Coroutine not functioning properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I have a coroutine that is used to track time and score. Every 10 seconds, the score is updated and a sound is played, and every 6 seconds, there is another sound. When the time goes to 0 game ends. This part is working fine. Problem is in the area that I have highlighted.

On a collision with checkpoint, I want to increment the time by 5 seconds and play a sound but the time is not incrementing on collision and the sound is not played. To debug, I added the `Debug.log("Collided")` line to make sure that collision is occurred, and the console shows collided when the collision occurs so there is no problem with the collision.

This is my checkpoint trigger code:

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    print("Hit checkpoint");
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CheckPointHit", 1);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Code for the coroutine

```cs
    IEnumerator LoseTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            currentTime--;

            if (currentTime % 10 == 0)
            {
                currentScore -= SCORE_INCREMENT;
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(scoreSound);
            }
            if (currentTime % 6 == 0)
            {
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(explosionSound);
            }

            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("CheckPointHit"))
            {
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CheckPointHit") == 1)
                {
                    currentTime += TIME_INCREMENT;
                    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(checkpointSound);
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CheckPointHit", 0);
                    Debug.Log("Collided");
                    Debug.Log(currentTime);
                }
            }

            if (currentTime <= 0)
                break;

            if (gameEnd == true)
                break;
        }

        GameOver();
    }
```

On a collision with checkpoint, I want to increment the time by 5 seconds and play a sound but the time is not incrementing on collision and the sound is not played.

Update: As per the debug statement, `Debug.Log(currentTime);`, it seems that the time is incrementing but it not incrementing in the display.

The function to display is below and I am calling it in `Update()`:

```cs
private void UpdateLabels()
{
    tmScore.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
    tmTimeLeft.text = "Time Left: " + currentTime; 
}
```

Comment: "Code for the coroutine is in the image" - please don't do that. Code is naturally text based. It's *much* easier to read when it's inline as text in the post. Please edit your post to include the relevant code directly as text - or ideally, a [mcve].

Comment: "the score is not incrementing on collision" - did you mean the time? We don't know anything about how the time is being displayed. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see whether it's *actually* increasing? Is `TIME_INCREMENT` definitely non-zero? As for the sound - are other sounds playing? Are you able to play `checkPointSound` at other times?

Comment: yes, the time is not incrementing. I double checked and it seems the time is increasing as per the debug.log statement but on the display its not.  I have updated the display code in the question.

Yes, all other sounds are working and I am able to play checkPointSound at other times.

Answer (score 0):

This method of your coding is very heavy. Keep in mind that the `GameObject.Find` and `GetComponent` functions are among the heaviest and should be avoided when there is no need for them.

```cs
private Camera camera; // cached Camera
void Start()
{
    camera = Camera.main;
    //...
}
```

Before playing the sound, make sure that the `AudioListener` and `AudioSource` are set correctly. For testing, it is better to test on 2D.

[image: 2D]

And then it's enough to write the following code, if the error is not resolved when running `Debug.Log`, the sound problem is not from your code.

```cs
[SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;
...

audioSource.PlayOneShot(soundClip); // better way to play sounds..
```